# BUtton click refresh Primary tab

Tags: apex

I have service console consisting 3 sections. In third section which is on right side consting on command button. if it clicks records are getting inserted on 2nd section. But same time the second page should also needs to be refreshed.

Any idea how to do?

**************************************VF************************************

```
<apex:page standardController="Case" extensions="GEBSC_ArticleCase" showHeader="false" sidebar="false" id="header1">


<apex:messages title="Knowledge Article"/>
<apex:pageBlock >

<apex:form > 

<strong> <font style="color:blue;"> <apex:outputText value="Articles related to case # {!Case.CaseNumber}:"/> </font> </strong>

<table cellpadding="3%" width="100%">
<tr bgcolor="#9f9fa3">

<td> <apex:inputCheckbox > 

 <apex:actionSupport event="onclick" onsubmit="checkAll(this)" rerender="false"/> 
  </apex:inputCheckbox>
  <strong> <font style="color:black;"> <apex:outputText value="Articles Title"/> </font></strong> 

  &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;

  <apex:commandButton value="Attach" action="{!saveKA}" onClick="doPrimaryTabRefresh(); "/> 

  </td>
  </tr>


  <apex:repeat value="{!kaListWrapper}" var="k">
   <tr>

  <td> <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!k.isselected}"> </apex:inputCheckbox>
    {!k.ka.title} </td>  </tr>


</apex:repeat>

</table>
</apex:form>


</apex:pageBlock>
<script>
function checkAll(cb)
{
var inputElem = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
for(var i=0; i<inputElem.length; i++)
{
if(inputElem[i].id.indexOf("checkedone")!=-2)
inputElem[i].checked = cb.checked;
}
}   

</script>

<apex:includeScript value="/support/console/22.0/integration.js"/>
<script type="text/javascript">

 var refreshPrimaryTab = function showTabId(result) {
        var tabId = result.id;
        sforce.console.refreshPrimaryTabById(tabId, true);

    };

    function doPrimaryTabRefresh() {
        sforce.console.getEnclosingPrimaryTabId(refreshPrimaryTab);

    }
     doPrimaryTabRefresh();  


    </script>


</apex:page>
```

*****************************Controller*****************************

```
public with sharing class GEBSC_ArticleCase{


private final Case theCase;

Public String KnowledgeArticleId {get;set;} 
Public List<String> newKMID {get;set;}
Set<Id> oldCaIdList = new Set<Id>();
Public List<wrapKA> kaListWrapper{get;set;}
public List<GEBSCBAGS__kav> kaInsertList = new List<GEBSCBAGS__kav>();

public List<CaseArticle> InsertList = new List<CaseArticle>();

public GEBSC_ArticleCase(ApexPages.StandardController stdController){



    theCase=(Case)StdController.getRecord();
    newKMID = new List<String>();    
    Set<Id> AccId = new Set<Id>(); 

    List<CaseArticle> oldCaList = [SELECT Id, CaseId, KnowledgeArticleId FROM CaseArticle WHERE CaseId =: theCase.id];    

    if(oldCaList.size()>0){ 
          for(CaseArticle ca : oldCaList){
              oldCaIdList.add(ca.KnowledgeArticleId); 
          } 
       }     


    List<Case> CaseNew= [Select id,GEBSCClientNameLookup__c from Case where id=:theCase.id]; 

    kaListWrapper = new List<wrapKA>();

    if(CaseNew.size()>0) {    
        for(Case nCase : CaseNew){
            if(nCase.GEBSCClientNameLookup__c!=null)
            AccId.add(nCase.GEBSCClientNameLookup__c);
        }    
    }

    List<GEBSCBAGS__kav> BAGS = [SELECT Id,title, KnowledgeArticleId, GEBSCClientName__c 
                                FROM GEBSCBAGS__kav WHERE GEBSCClientName__c IN: AccId
                                AND PublishStatus='Online' AND language ='en_US'
                                AND KnowledgeArticleId NOT IN: oldCaIdList ]; 



    if(BAGS.size()>0){
        for(Case newCase : CaseNew){
            for(GEBSCBAGS__kav art_b : BAGS){
                if(newCase.GEBSCClientNameLookup__c== art_b.GEBSCClientName__c){        
                    newKMID.add(art_b.title);
                    kaListWrapper.add(new wrapKA(art_b));        
                }
            }
        }
    }



}

public void saveKA(){

System.PageReference redirect;




    if(!kaListWrapper.isEmpty()){
        for(wrapKA wrap : kaListWrapper){
            if(wrap.isSelected){
                kaInsertList.add(wrap.ka);
            }
        }
        if(!kaInsertList.isEmpty()){

        for(GEBSCBAGS__kav temp :kaInsertList){     

            CaseArticle newCA = new CaseArticle();

                         newCA.CaseId = theCase.Id;
                         newCA.KnowledgeArticleId = temp.KnowledgeArticleId;
                         InsertList.add(newCA); 

                     }

             if(InsertList.size()>0){
              insert InsertList;
                 }
        }
    }

}

public class wrapKA{
    public GEBSCBAGS__kav ka{get;set;}
    public boolean isSelected{get;set;}

       public wrapKA(GEBSCBAGS__kav a){
         ka=a;
         isselected=false;
       }
  }

}
```

I used refreshing primary tab but its going in loop to refresh everytime.